# eclipse android sdk does not update code after changes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

## problem:

nothing seems to be wrong,no any error infomation,but changes in code no longer takes effect even for the simplest example.i.e:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rdo_todo:
            if (checked){
                Log.e("actedit", "rdo click22");
                }
            break;
        case R.id.rdo_reminder:
            if (checked){
                TimePickerDialog_doofin.newInstance(0, 10, true)
                .show(getFragmentManager(), "tpddf");
                
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

add some logger:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    Log.e("actedit", "rdo click???");
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rdo_todo:
            if (checked){
                Log.e("actedit", "rdo click22");
                }
            break;
        case R.id.rdo_reminder:
            if (checked){
                TimePickerDialog_doofin.newInstance(0, 10, true)
                .show(getFragmentManager(), "tpddf");
                Log.e("actedit", "rdo click rm");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

when i click the radio buttons,the logger does not show.Other changes in code also didn't take effect in devices.

## what i've tried but no effect

I view the source file in disk,it did changed.delete apk from device and reinstall apk in debug mode ,the problem remains.
clean project
delete *.* at project's bin folder
delete .metadate file and re-import project,still no use!!

## my view

there must be some place for eclipse to hide/store the old code,but where is it??
from this link: [Java Code not properly updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737105/java-code-not-properly-updating)

> If none of these work, then I believe there could be some kind of lock in the file system
> but i have reboot several times,and use vim to see that the source code actually changes

## extra info

i use android sdk with eclipse juno.

## cause

there were 3 versions of android sdks in computer before:4.2.2,4.4.2,4.4w,i mainly use 4.4.2.
yesterday i deleted 4.4.2 sdk and start using 4.4w sdk ,the problem occurs after that.

## most weired is:i deleted every file in .metadata and project's own bin folder,but when i ran app,it still give me result from old code !

## update

i start a new project,the code is behaves normally,no prob.
so i copy old project's bin and src folder to the new one,hope the problem can be solved,but it remains...

Comment: Are you sure *Build Automatically* is checked? Also if you delete .metadata, you cannot open the Eclipse project anymore, so that makes no sense.

Comment: yeah it is checked,and the workspace can be opened some how

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a refresh on the entire project, and after that, make a clean.

In eclipse:
Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects.

Then, run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

Is your function `onRadioButtonClicked` invoked at all?
You may confirm that by debuging.

If you have breakpoint inside `onRadioButtonClicked`, click radio button and debuger is not stopping- have you assigned onRadioButtonClicked function to your radio (in layout xml file, or in code)?

There are two optons to add listener

### Setting radio button listener from xml layout file

`android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` in your `RadioButton` tag.

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pirates"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
```

### Setting radio button listener from java code

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
    }
});
```

Comment: yes it is called.when i click it,i just got old debug info

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Ant/Maven/Gradle build for your project? 
If yes, then

1. delete target/bin directories
2. **rebuild from command line** (not from IDE)
3. check that artifact has correct (new) date
4. redeploy